# Fibers and Push-forward

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, alternative-proof

Let $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$ be a surjective morphism of projective varieties. Consider a non-singular irreducible projective curve $T$ and surjective morphism $p_Y\colon Y\longrightarrow T$. Then we get the following commutative diagram $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X_t @>f_t>>  Y_t\\
    @V  V V @VV  V\\
    X @>f>> Y\\
    @Vp_X  V V @Vp_YV  V\\
    T @>>\mathsf{id}_T> T
\end{CD} so in particular an induced map between fibers $f_t\colon X_t\longrightarrow Y_t$. I would to check the following result:

**Result:** Let $V\subseteq X$ be an irreducible projective variety such that $\dim V=\dim W$, where $W:=f(V)$. Denote by $[V_t]$ the cycle associated to the projective variety $p_X^{-1}(t)\cap V$ and by $f_\ast$ the push-forward induced by $f$.  Then $$(\#) \: \: \: \:(f_t)_\ast([V_t])=\big[f_\ast[V]\big]_t=\deg(f_{|V})[W_t].$$ This is a well know formula (eg. *Prop.* 10.1 of [**Ful**]), but in the reference I cited the Author proves it in a different way. Indeed, he consider intersection fibers instead of cycle associated to scheme theoretic fibers as I am doing.

**My Attempt:** We can assume that $V$ and $Y$ are affine and $f$ is dominant. Denote the coordinate rings of the fibers $V_t,W_t$ by $A:=k[V_t]$ and $R=k[W_t]$. Then we have $$(f_t)_\ast[V_t]=\sum_S\ell(A_{\mathfrak q_S})\deg({f_t}_{|S})f_t(S),$$ where $S$ runs over the irreducible components of $V_t$ such that  $\dim f(S)=dim W-1$. On the other hand, we have 
$$\deg(f_{|V})\cdot[W_t]=[k(V):k(W)]\cdot\sum_Z\ell(R_{\mathfrak p_Z})Z,$$ where $Z$ runs over the irreducible components of $W_t$. Now fix an irreducible component $Z$ (corresponding to the minimal prime $\mathfrak p\subset R$) and consider the irreducible components $S_1,\ldots,S_n$ of $V_t$ (corresponding to the minimal primes $\mathfrak q_1,\ldots \mathfrak q_n\subset A$) whose image via $f_t$ is just $Z$. Proving $(\#)$ is then equivalent to provving the following formula $$[k(V):k(W)]\cdot\ell(R_\mathfrak p)=\sum_{i=1}^n[k(\mathfrak q_i):k(\mathfrak p)]\cdot\ell(A_{\mathfrak q_i}).$$

A similar aproach can be found [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02R6). More precisely, this [lemma](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02M0) should be the key-point of the proof.

**Add**: The proof of this result would be important because one could check that the push-forward preserves algebraic equivalence of cycles by considering the following commutative diagram:

\begin{CD}
\lbrace t\rbrace\times X @>f>> \lbrace t \rbrace\times Y\\
    @V  V V @VV  V\\
    T\times X @>\mathsf{id}\times f>> T\times Y\\
    @Vp_X  V V @Vp_YV  V\\
    T @>>\mathsf{id}_T> T
\end{CD}

Thanks in advance for any help.

[**Ful**] Fulton, W. (1988) *Intersection Theory*. New York: Springer-Verlag.

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer to my own question. At least, if someone will struggle with my same proplem in the future he will can find a solution.

The formula I was tempting to prove is actually true, with some modification. More precisely, in the Handbook of K-Theory (ed. Grayson and Friedlander), Thomas Geisser, in his paper *[Motivic Cohomology, K-Theory and Topological Cyclic Homology](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-3-540-27855-9_6)* proves the following result.

[image]

By mean of standard geometric arguments, He deduces that it is enough to check the claim in the affine case and consider $V$ in place of $X$ and $f(V)$ in place of $Y$. Thus, the proposition is proved by showing the formula

[image]